# How do I plot confidence intervals for a GEV distribution in MATLAB?

Tags: confidence-interval

I need to create a plot like the attached image which is a GEV distribution. I have got the distribution parameters from gevfit(x), but not sure how I can add the observed data and confidence intervals. Any help is appreciated.

Regards JameZ

[Confidence Limits plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wg7mb.png)

I have seen this link but not sure if that does the work.

[text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600260/how-do-i-plot-confidence-intervals-in-matlab/76914498#76914498)

Also this link is close to what I want but no codes is included
[text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62076400/plotting-confidence-interval-around-predicted-line-plot)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Hi, could you please be clearer, do you mean the body of question? I need to crate a graph like the example attached. Any help is appreciated!